# How to create a Funnel in Google Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

The tutorials all say to do it on the Goals page, but there is no UI for Funnels on the Goals page for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Under the Admin section of Google Analytics, click the Goal option underneath the VIEW (PROFILE) tier. Once you are on the Goal creation page, select 'Destination' as your type.
2. Once you've done that, click next and the page should show you Goal Details. From here, put in your destination URL i.e. the final step of your funnel.
3. To add steps to your funnel, toggle the Funnel switch to On and fill in the funnel URI's.

You can check to see if you've setup your funnel correctly by click the 'Verify this Goal' link.

Let me know if I didn't understand your question correctly. Happy to help.

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense.  So, you cannot have a funnel with an end goal that is not a destination?  I want to make an event the end goal.

Comment: What you could do though is have a virtual pageview fire off along with the event. Then you could use the virtual pageview as a destination URL.